# (mac) dockers , how to connect to a redis server in the hosting machine from a containter

Tags: macos, networking, redis, docker, boot2docker

i am running a docker container on my mac machine using `boot2docker`:

I want to connect to `redis-server` i am running my hosting machine from inside the container.

1. I have managed to connect from the container to a service i am running on the host machine using `curl http://192.168.3.124:5000` (getting results)
2. I have managed to connect to it , but I am not pulling data from it according to it's state. 
   `redisServer = redis.StrictRedis(host='192.168.3.124', port= "6379"); redisServer.get("2") (gets no results, from the hosting machine that key is set)`

*details*:
running the redis server :

```
[58781] 13 May 13:53:16.120 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.19
[58781] 13 May 13:53:16.120 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[58781] 13 May 13:53:16.120 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

`ps aux |grep redis`

```
partuck         58781   0.0  0.0  2469924   1652 s002  S+    1:53PM   0:00.03 redis-server *:6379
partuck         58728   0.0  0.7  2583104 115260   ??  S     1:53PM   0:00.47 /usr/local/opt/redis/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

from the

Answer (score 0):

Your host IP in the virtualbox that boot2docker setups is (typically) 10.0.2.2.

So you should try connecting to 10.0.2.2:6379